# Lets Encryptにて、接続できないと言う判定になる(動的IP)

Tags: ssl

現在Debianにて、RapidSSL WildCardの値上げ(1万円→2万円)に伴い、Lets Encryptへの乗り換えを検討中です。
VPS上のCentOSでは正常に動作し、一切問題無く動作させることは出来たのですが、自宅サーバー（動的IP）で認証に失敗している状況です。自動で上手くいかなかったので、--manualにて導入を試みています。

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --manual -d #MY-DOMAIN# --server HTTPS://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

まず上記のコマンドで、キーとなるファイルの作成に取り掛かりました。

```
http://#MY-DOMAIN#/.well-known/acme-challenge/#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#
```

でアクセスできるよう、求められるので、該当の「#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#」に「#LONG-RANDOM-STRING#」を書き込みました。表示されたとおりのコマンド print "%S" #LONG-RANDOM-STRING# > #LONG-RANDOm-FILENAME# や、「echo "#LONG-RANDOM-STRING#" > #LONG-RANDOm-FILENAME#」等を試しました。
ブラウザから指定のURLにアクセスすれば見えることを確認し、リターンしました。すると次のようなエラーが帰ってきました。

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: #MY-DOMAIN#
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Could not connect to
   http://#MY-DOMAIN#/.well-known/acme-challenge/#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

と、アクセスが出来ないエラーとなっているので、ルーターやサーバーのファイヤーウォールを無効にしましたが換わりなく、DigにてDNSをチェックしても、一ヶ月以上前から変わっていないIPがAレコードに入っているのを確認しました。

```
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;#MY-DOMAIN#.                    IN      A

   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   #MY-DOMAIN#.             120     IN      A       #MY-SERVER-IPADDR#
```

しかし、サーバーのアクセスログ、エラーログを確認したところ、認証サーバーからのアクセスが無い様で、認証サーバーに、正しいIPアドレスが伝わっていないように思われます。
このような場合、どうすれば宜しいでしょうか？

Comment: サーバーの手前にルータがあるということは、サーバのIPアドレスがプライベートアドレス(IPアドレスが、0.で始まる、172.xx.で始まっていて16<xx<31、192.168.で始まるのいずれか）なのではありませんか？

Comment: その通りです・・・つまり、サーバー本体にAレコードで指定されているグローバルIPアドレスが必須、ということですか？

Comment: エラーの説明の中に"please check that  your computer has a publicly routable IP address"とありますから、いわゆる「グローバルIPアドレス」が求められています。　　ルータのWAN側にはパブリックIPアドレスが付与されているはずですから、自宅サーバをWANに（ルータを介さないで）直結してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: なるほど・・・すごくヒントになった気がします。参考に探ってみます。

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして。
ぼくも似たようなケースでacme-challengeができなかったのですが、解決した経緯があったので、可能性としてお伝えしてみます。

ルーター内からスクリプトを走らせると名前解決ができない例に該当するようなので、hostsにドメイン名とローカルipを設定すると自分の場合は成功しました。

あ、ポートフォーワードされていることは前提となります。

Answer (score -1):

> 認証サーバーに、正しいIPアドレスが伝わっていないように思われます

お使いのドメインのDNSサーバーの設定が適切でないと見受けられます。
ドメインを取得した際のレジストラに申請しているDNSサーバーがあると思いますが
そちらのDNSサーバー上に 自宅サーバーのグローバルIPを登録してください。

登録の例：
Name: www.example.com  <- あなたのサーバーホスト名
Type: A
Value: 198.51.100.2    <- あなたのサーバーグローバルIP

動作確認の例: Google Public DNS で自分のドメインを検索して正しいIPが返ればOK

```
$ dig a www.example.com @8.8.8.8 
; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P5 <<>> example.com a @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3237
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            86399   IN      A       198.51.100.2

;; Query time: 316 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: 月 10月 02 17:55:19 JST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```